# Cocoapods and forked repo issue

Tags: github, cocoapods, git-fork

So here's my podfile:

```
workspace 'WSPhoto.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, :deployment_target => "6.1"

xcodeproj 'WSPhoto'

pod 'Parse-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.2.17'
pod 'REActivityViewController',  :git => 'https://github.com/ramsel/REActivityViewController.git', :commit => 'f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef'
pod 'SWTableViewCell', :git => 'https://github.com/ramsel/SWTableViewCell.git', :commit => '6f4e55e554c1b26ff3c850eb331273b536e4f900'
pod 'ELCImagePickerController', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'ChimpKit'
```

I'm forking a couple repos and pointing Cocoapods to specific commits of my forks based on the advice in my previous question:

[CocoaPods and GitHub forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-fork)

However, I get the following error on `pod install --verbose`:

```
Fetching external sources
-> Pre-downloading: `REActivityViewController` from `https://github.com/ramsel/REActivityViewController.git`, commit `f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef`
 > GitHub download
   $ /usr/bin/git config core.bare
   true
   $ /usr/bin/git config core.bare
   true
   $ /usr/bin/git rev-list --max-count=1
   f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef
   fatal: bad object f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef
   [!] Failed: /usr/bin/git rev-list --max-count=1
   f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef
 > Cloning to Pods folder
     $ /usr/bin/git clone
     "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/4a2fb7e9e50f5b0922a251d6b2763
     d6d37629fda"
     "/Users/admin/Dropbox/Apps/things/Pods/REActivityViewController"
     Cloning into '/Users/admin/Dropbox/Apps/things/Pods/REActivityViewController'...
     done.
     Checking connectivity... done
   $ /usr/bin/git checkout -b activated-pod-commit
   f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef 2>&1
   fatal: reference is not a tree: f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef
[!] Pod::Executable checkout -b activated-pod-commit f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef 2>&1

fatal: reference is not a tree: f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef
```

I tried referencing a different my fork of `REActivityViewController` but same error. I commented out the `REActivityViewController` line in my podfile and the fork of SWTableViewCell install fine.

So I'm thinking it's something particular to my `REActivityViewController` fork but it's not particular to a specific commit in that fork.

Answer (score 12):

So this worked:

```
pod 'REActivityViewController',  :git => 'https://github.com/ramsel/REActivityViewController.git', :commit => 'f027011e8159393cf678d7c67c408891b609a6ef',  :branch => 'master'
```

I just had to add:

```
:branch => 'master'
```