# How to use AppDelegate.h file in Pod project ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to use AppDelegate.h file in pod project viewControllers,for that I need to access the AppDelegate class in Pod Project.

Comment: What do you mean by **AppDelegate class in Pod Project**?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do like that. Already this question has been answered here [Modify existing pod in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625579/modify-existing-pod-in-xcode)

Answers:

1. You should not do it this way, you should just extend the class from the pod you are using your project and add the necessary change in the derived class.
2. Pods should not be directly edited, as any subsequent 'pod install' will wipe out your changes. As stated by rckoenes the easiest approach is to subclass the relevant class and add what you need.
   If the changes you need can't be done in a subclass, you have another option. You can fork the repo for the pod, make any needed changes directly to the classes themselves, and point your podfile towards your fork.