# How to install a pod from a specific branch?

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying add add a pod by cocoapods, and I am using swift 3, while the pod([SQlite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/master)).

I am trying to use doesn't have a master of the latest swift version, however there is a [branch](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/swift3-mariotaku) for swift 3.

So how should I set my podfile to download the specific branch? Is it possible?

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'RedShirt' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RedShirt
   pod 'SQLite.swift', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 333, accepted):

The [podfile guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo) mentions the following syntax:

> To use a different branch of the repo:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'
                                                                             ^^^
                                                                   (the space is important)
```

So in your case, that would be:

```
pod 'SQLite.swift', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git', :branch => 'swift3-mariotaku'
```

Comment: Tag syntax `:tag => '1.0.0'`

Comment: @AndrewMorris True. And Commit syntax: `:commit => '0f506b1c45'`

Comment: Is this a good way to install pod using branch ? I don't think so. We should either use commitId or tags.

Comment: @SrijanKumar I agree. The point of the answer was simply to illustrate a possible syntax, not to recommend a best practice.

Comment: Yes Yes I am just highlighting best practice :)

Comment: @SrijanKumar I've done this before, because I wanted to point to their non-master branch. The master branch was in Swift 3, but I wanted the Swift2 branch. I'm doing it again now, because I have a private pod, which I want to point to and make a pull request in my host app. During the pull request review period, it will point to my branch. Once my colleagues approve it, then I will revert it from pointing to that branch. Update the tag on my private pod + bump the version in my podfile.

Comment: @VonC do you even do any iOS development? :D

Comment: @Honey No, I do not. I do agree the scenario you are describing is a valid case for installing a pod from a branch though.

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to use the main branch (master), write the following command:

```
pod "SAConfettiView", :git => 'https://github.com/oskarko/SAConfettiView.git'
```

But if you want to use an alternative/different branch, this one is for you:

```
pod "SAConfettiView", :git => 'https://github.com/oskarko/SAConfettiView.git', :branch => 'develop'
```

Easy peasy!

Answer (score 8):

**Cocoapods with specific branch**

[[Cocoapods]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877)

Use `:branch` in `Podfile`

```
pod "SQLite.swift", :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git', :branch => 'dev'

//additionally you can use :tag, :commit
```

Please note, that branch must contain `.podspec` in root directory

When you specify `:branch`, Cocoapods will try to find `.podspec` directly there instead of searching in centralized repository

[[Local CocoaPods]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812997/4770877)