# Cannot link forked library to project via CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebaseui, git-fork

I am experiencing a strange issue and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am forking from [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS) in order to set it up for my needs.

**What I want to do:**

I want to remove the "Back" text from the navigation bar because I have a custom image back button and it is now colliding with the lib's back item. I cannot customize that through the SDK's Api so I decided to remove the lines that are setting the "Back" text in 2 view controllers.

**What I did:**

So I forked the repo and made the changes directly through the GitHub web interface. I committed my changes in my forked repo.

**What I've tried:**

**1.** I followed this post [CocoaPods and GitHub forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-forks) and tried the first suggestion - pointing CocoaPods to use my forked repo with my latest commit. I got `[!] Failed to download 'FirebaseUI'.` error when I did `pod update`.

**2.** I tried the second suggestion in the post - cloning my forked repo with the needed changes and pointing to it as a local pod. I was able to `pod update` but then I got build errors in Xcode - `Duplicate interface definition for class`.

Is it possible that this happens because FirebaseUI consists of different sub-libraries and I only need to use 3 of them? This is what I want to use as in my Podfile:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
```

This is how my Podfile look like:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', :path => '~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google', :path => '~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook', :path => '~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS'
```

and Podfile.lock

```
PODS:
- FirebaseUI/Auth (5.2.2):
- Firebase/Auth (~> 5.0)
- FirebaseUI/Facebook (5.2.2):
- FBSDKLoginKit (~> 4.0)
- FirebaseUI/Auth
- FirebaseUI/Google (5.2.2):
- FirebaseUI/Auth
- GoogleSignIn (~> 4.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
- FirebaseUI/Auth (from `~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS`)
- FirebaseUI/Facebook (from `~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS`)
- FirebaseUI/Google (from `~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS`) 

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
FirebaseUI:
:path: "~/Developer/Forked/FirebaseUI-iOS"
```

The exact error message in Xcode:

```
../Pods/FirebaseUI/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIAuthBaseViewController.h:28:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'FUIAuthBaseViewController'
```

Where `FUIAuthBaseViewController` is one of 2 edited view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-forks), the pod specifier in the Podfile should reference a source location for the forked repo like:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', :git => 'https://github.com/.../FirebaseUI.git', :commit => 'd35...2bc1'
```

I find the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29399077/556617) easier of pointing to a local path:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', :path => '~/mypath-to/FirebaseUI'
```

Make sure that all the FirebaseUI references are changed in the Podfile by examining the generated `Podfile.lock`.

If you're still having problems share the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` to help others diagnose.

Comment: Added that as well.