# Committing a POD change?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

iOS project on Xcode.
We do not keep the POD files as part of our repo.
A new change is needed and it is on a file from one of the PODS.
How do I go about committing such a change to the repo?

Comment: fork the repo, make the change. Then either use your fork or open a pull request to ask the owner to take in your change

Comment: sorry, but how do I make our repo use the forked pod

Comment: I’ve added it to an answer. It’s in the cocoa pod docs

Answer (score 0):

> but how do I make our repo use the forked pod

You can try and copy the SHA1 of your fix from your forked repository, and update your Podfile with it, as described in "[CocoaPods and GitHub forks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937937/6309)", follwoed by a `pod update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fork of the repo, make the change to a given branch, and then point your pod file to your repo + branch like this:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'
```

Or you can open a pull request and ask the owner to pull in your change. Depending on what your change does